# Qt5.2: When trying to build qtwebkit for Android get "LLIntAssembly.h: No such file..."

Tags: android, qt5, qtwebkit

Using the beta version of qt5.2.

After some effort, I was able to build everything for an Android platform except qtwebkit.
Note: Building on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

The message I'm seeing is:

```
llint/LowLevelInterpreter.cpp:551:27: fatal error: LLIntAssembly.h: No such file or directory
```

In searching both Qt and webkit forums, this error is supposed to have been fixed in the current version of qtwebkit, and indeed the code appears to contain the changes, yet the `LLIntAssembly.h` file is not being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Qt WebKit is not supported on Android, and probably never will be.

They're more likely going to go with the new Chromium-based [Qt Web Engine](https://www.qt.io/blog/2013/09/12/introducing-the-qt-webengine). This info is from Bogdan Vatra, the creator of the Qt Android port -- see the table of features at the bottom of his blog post: http://www.kdab.com/qt-on-android-episode-1/

***EDIT**: As of September 2019, You can use the lightweight Qt WebView module on Android and iOS: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-index.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-index.html_)*

Comment: Seems like it became possible with Qt 5.5 (https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtwebkit-goes-mobile.html)... but it might've been discontinued ? I haven't been able to dig anything else...

Comment: @Michael That article is very old. It came from a time before Android and iOS were invented: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-module.html For Android and iOS, you can use the lightweight Qt WebView module: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-index.html